# How can i render Google Maps Android API v2 on a TextureView?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

According to [this comment](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4782#c1), Google Maps Android API v2 relies on SurfaceView to display the map. And view animations doesn't work with SurfaceView. This is the problem that i'm facing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBWvRxV64WU (the MapView is flickering when the slide animation starts). I think that using TextureView this problem may not occur. So, how can i render Google Maps on a TextureView?

--- UPDATE ---
Google Maps Team fixed this issue on API 16: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4839

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, how can i render Google Maps on a TextureView?

Get a job at Google, join the Maps team, and implement a modification to the closed-source Maps V2 library to use `TextureView` on supported devices.

Otherwise, you cannot change this, as it is not open source, and therefore you cannot modify it.

Sorry!

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that. Is that any workaround to this animation bug?

Comment: @MarcosLopes: Sorry, I have no idea. Given that Cyril Mottier chimed in on that Maps V2 issue, I suspect that "it is what it is", as Cyril would certainly know.